# How to apply a current user specific theme to a sharepoint site

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, css, sharepoint-2010

I want to to provid a functionality in my sharepoint site 
I want to set the theme according to user. & that theme is specifically for that user

for e.g lets say if user a set his theme as theme1 and for other users its be default or other theme's according to them .

So next time when user1 a log in he should see the theme set by him. I.e theme1 .
same is the case with other users

Can any one help me what will be the best approch to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This SO link might be of some help [User specific theme in SharePoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153310/user-specific-theme-in-sharepoint)